# Trying to save a number in a new dataframe but nothing happens (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas df like this

```
a column
_____
NaN
e
NaN
b
```

I want to save the count of a non-nan values in a new dataframe:

```
df_ new=pd.DataFrame()

df_new['column1']= int(df["a column"].count())
```

My expected output is:

df_new

```
column1
2
```

but nothing happens.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'col1':[np.nan,'e',np.nan,'b']
    }
)
df
```

[image]

```
df2 = df.count()
df2
```

[image]

It's `series`.
We can check the type of `df2`

```
type(df2)
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

You could turn it into `DataFrame` by `to_frame()`

```
df3 = df.count().to_frame()
df3
```

[image]

```
type(df3)
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```